# Invalidate the $location in an AngularJS controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller, angular-ui-router

I am writing an Angular single page application where a number of "pages" are rendered through a common view and a common controller (using `ui-router`). The data to be used is stored in a hierarchical object in a service, and it is retrieved using the URL components. That is, if I have the URL `#/getstarted/get` the contents are read from `myService.getContents().getstarted.get`.

This works pretty good, but with one exception: When I want to navigate to another of these pages, nothing happens. In order to get to another page I have to visit a page that is controlled by another controller.

Obviously, when I click on the link to a state with the same controller that controller is not parsed again (which can be seen from "console.log debugging), and so the parameters to retrieve the data from are not refreshed.

Is there a way (in a callback, in module.config or in some incantation of `ui-sref`) to invalidate the controller data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some further research turned out that it actually was the `ui-sref` part that has to be updated. Concretely: Adding `ui-sref-opts="{reload: true}"` causes the controller data to be reinterpreted. So I had to add this directive to all the ui-sref links in the template to activate the behaviour I need.

This is documented on http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.directive:ui-sref, but it has to be mentioned that there is no example of how to format the object itself.

Answer (score 0):

If you had a plunkr, would be easier to test but try a variant of:

```
$stateProvider.state('somewhere', {
  url:'/somewhere',
  cache:false,
  templateUrl:function(params) {
      return 'some/calculated/path/view.html'
  },
  controllerProvider:[function() {
    return 'HomeController';
  }]
});
```

`templateUrl` and `controllerProvider` should be called each time...

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't help. Even when the *names* are passed back from functions the controller seems not to be executed again. Maybe the problem is because I have more levels of nesting. I can share the temporary location of the website stub at https://openlilylib.org/newsite/app, with the routes defined in scripts/app.js (it's about app.tabbed and its children), the controllers (TabbedContentController) in scripts/controllers.js and the factory (tabbedContentFactory) in scripts/services.js.

Comment: shouldn't your state be abstract                 .state('app.tabbed', {
                    url: '',
                    views: {
                        'content@': {
                            templateUrl : 'views/tabbed-content.html',
                            controller : 'TabbedContentController'
                        }
                    }
                })

Comment: Also, is that dynamic? Does it change without the browser page refreshing?
If so, `homeFactory` could just return the whole state object or an array of them...

Comment: One thing I had tried is to turn all variables in the controller into functions, as I thought I might be trapped in a closure. I didn't succeed with that, but if anybody tells me that's the right approach I would take a step back and maybe rewrite the controller with that in mind?

Comment: Your site https://openlilylib.org/newsite/app/#/getstarted/get-openlilylib seems to navigate well, what's wrong precisely?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by abstract (in the sense of object orientation?). What you quote is exactly my current .state, isn't it? Should I change that?
With regard to "dynamic": It works (without page reload) when I'm on a tabbed page (e.g. Get Involved -> Get in Touch), then change to a non-tabbed page, say, Home, and then go to another tabbed page. So as soon as I enter another controller everything is fine. It seems that when a go to another route with the same controller this isn't properly handled.

Comment: To be clear about the issue: Go to "About->openLilyLib". Then try to go to any subpage, e.g. "Get Started->Get openLilyLib". This does not work. If you go to Home or Packages first you can access another tabbed page.

Comment: Abstract: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-and-Nested-Views#abstract-states